# Why can't I slice a column as I can a row?

Tags: python, list

I have a Sudoku Board as this list,

```
board = [   ['.', 2, '.', '.', '.', 4, 3, '.', '.'], 
            [9, '.', '.', '.', 2, '.', '.', '.', 8], 
            ['.', '.', '.', 6, '.', 9, '.', 5, '.'], 
            ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 1], 
            ['.', 7, 2, 5, '.', 3, 6, 8, '.'], 
            [6, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
            ['.', 8, '.', 2, '.', 5, '.', '.', '.'], 
            [1, '.', '.', '.', 9, '.', '.', '.', 3], 
            ['.', '.', 9, 8, '.', '.', '.', 6, '.']    ]
```

I can easily check a certain value is present in a row or not so effortlessly by,
`value in board[row][:]` but I can't do the same thing for a column. For example, when I write `value in board[:][col]` **it somehow picks the `row`, indexed with the value `col` and then tries to find the specified `value`.**

For example, `print(board[6][:])` gives `['.', 8, '.', 2, '.', 5, '.', '.', '.']` (**7th row**) and `print(board[:][2])` gives `['.', '.', '.', 6, '.', 9, '.', 5, '.']` (**3rd row**).
I'm really confused why it is the case.

My question is, **is there an equivalent syntax of `board[row][:]` for a column? And more importantly why `board[:][col]` doesn't work?**

Comment: You are representing your board as a list of rows, so there's no direct way to access all the elements in a particular column. You could do something like what you want with numpy arrays or pandas dataframes. With your structure, you need something like `value in [row[column] for row in board]` or `any(row[column] == value for row in board)`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp great. I understand it now. Thanks.
And this is exactly what I wanted :).

```[row, col] = [6, 4]
print(3 in [row[col] for row in board])```

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent syntax is `zip(*board)[2][:]`:

```
>>> zip(*board)[2][:]
('.', '.', '.', '.', 2, '.', '.', '.', 9)
>>> 2 in zip(*board)[2][:]
True
```

See [documentation for `zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Your method doesn't work because `board[:]` means "all rows", i.e. the same thing as `board`. So `board[:][2]` is equivalent to `board[2]`. You don't need the `[:]` part in `value in board[row][:]` either.

To be clear, the `[:]` syntax is commonly used for [copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list), as @VPfB mentioned. Since you are only reading the list, it doesn't matter (and in fact slighly less efficient because you are creating an in-memory copy of the whole board).

Comment: I think it should be noted that `board[:]` is not exactly the same thing as `board`. It is a copy. It means the same when the program is only reading from it, but not when it is writing to it.

Comment: @VPfB Correct, thanks for the clarification. Incorporated that info into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes on how indexing works in Python. This might clear it up a bit:

```py
board = [
    [".", 2, ".", ".", ".", 4, 3, ".", "."],
    [9, ".", ".", ".", 2, ".", ".", ".", 8],
    [".", ".", ".", 6, ".", 9, ".", 5, "."],
    [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 1],
    [".", 7, 2, 5, ".", 3, 6, 8, "."],
    [6, ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
    [".", 8, ".", 2, ".", 5, ".", ".", "."],
    [1, ".", ".", ".", 9, ".", ".", ".", 3],
    [".", ".", 9, 8, ".", ".", ".", 6, "."],
]

first = board[0]
second = board[0][0]

# Prints the row, as expected.
print(first)  # ['.', 2, '.', '.', '.', 4, 3, '.', '.']

# Prints the value of the INDEX in the row[0].
print(second)  # .

# Finds the actual column values by iterating through the values in index 0 of all the rows.
column = []
for row in board:
    column.append(row[0])  # Row number 0.

print(column) # ['.', 9, '.', '.', '.', 6, '.', 1, '.']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NumPy, you can access column values easily.

```
>> board = numpy.array([
    [".", 2, ".", ".", ".", 4, 3, ".", "."],
    [9, ".", ".", ".", 2, ".", ".", ".", 8],
    [".", ".", ".", 6, ".", 9, ".", 5, "."],
    [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 1],
    [".", 7, 2, 5, ".", 3, 6, 8, "."],
    [6, ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
    [".", 8, ".", 2, ".", 5, ".", ".", "."],
    [1, ".", ".", ".", 9, ".", ".", ".", 3],
    [".", ".", 9, 8, ".", ".", ".", 6, "."],
])

>> board[:,0]
>> array([".", 9, ".",".",".",6,".",1,"."])
```